# What C++ Mocking framework should i use?

Tags: c++, mocks

What C++ Mocking framework should i use? I've tried Gmock but it requires My methods to be Virtual and I am not able to change the method type, I also tried Isolator++ which doesn't require that but its commercial. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. If you don’t want to pay, please add either the [tag:gratis] or [tag:open-source] tag. Your question is so broad that you may as well just look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C++). If you have more requirements then you will probably get an answer here. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for making it clear, commercial is an option but not 1000$ a piece
My biggest requirement is the ability to mock without changing my code, I havent seen this parameter in the comparison of Wikipedia, thats why I posted it here

Comment: No problem - it's a good answer (upvote). A ***great*** answer addresses every point of the question ;-) Thanks again for your help